# Animate text movement with html5 and / or CSS3

Tags: html, animation, css

What i want to do is have a bit of text, say "Ipsum Lorem..." slide horizontaly into a coloured DIV fast-ish, then ease to a near-stop, but keep moving slowly, then ease up to high speed and off out of the DIV - it also must not be visible outside the div.

I know i could do this in flash easily, but im trying to avoid using it...!

Is this even possible? as its sort of time-lined.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible using Javascript. You can try looking into Adobe's new HTML5 editor. It's called Adobe Edge. They had free trials a while back, though I don't know if that's still going on, but it should be able to assist you in creating this animation.